# SQL CLR C# and SqlConnection object

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlclr

Fairly new to SQL CLR development. I have a need to use the context connection in multiple C# functions within the UserDefinedFunctions class. Question is related to whether or not it is better to

1. Create a context connection in function #1 which is then passed to function #2, #3, etc.
2. Create a new context connection in each function that needs to query the database.
3. Create a instance variable on the class and use that across all functions.
4. Create 1 "query" function and pass it the query string/parameters and have all querying be done in one function. This option would effectively be creating and destroying the connection on each call right?
5. Open to other ideas.

Not sure what the best practice is on handling the context connection when it is needed in various places within the code.

Would prefer to use `using (SqlConnection connection...) {}` to ensure things are properly disposed of but perhaps could also use the destructor on the class to do this as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Context Connection` is the in-process connection so you can only open it once. And since it is "in-process", SQL Server does not need to allocate new resources for the connection like it does with a regular / external connection that needs to create a new SPID, etc (and hence why we have connection pooling to mitigate that cost). Hence, I do not know how much performance would be improved for all of this effort.

You *can* pass that `SqlConnection` object down to other methods, but you need to weigh the costs / benefits of reducing a very minimal amount of overhead (as compared to making a new, external connection) with the fact that you cannot pass information back at the same time that the Context Connection is open.

You would not want to create an instance variable as that would force the Assembly to require being set with a `PERMISSION_SET` of `UNSAFE`. The issue is that the class is instantiated the first time a method within it is called and it stays in memory until the App Domain is unloaded or possibly some other event, but in either case, it stays resident for quite some time. The class is also shared across all users who call the methods within it, which is why a class level variable is problematic as it would be shared across SPIDs. This is why all methods must be `static`.

You can use a `using` construct, but you are thinking in the wrong terms by looking at this at the class level. The class is instantiated once and shared across all users on the system.

For more information on SQLCLR, I am writing a series about it on SQL Server Central:
[Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I need to keep it SAFE. So are you saying options 1,2,4 are viable options? And option 1 may not be worth it depending on what work is being performed? And I very much appreciate the technical details - I now better understand what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Can you help me understand "with the fact that you cannot pass information back at the same time that the Context Connection is open". Pass data back to the caller in SQL Server or pass data back to a calling function (returning) in C#?

Comment: @thomas : You should test to see what the relative difference is for # 1. I "think" that the cost of creating / destroying a "Context Connection = true" `SqlConnection` is close to nothing considering that you are already attached to the SQL Server process. I don't have stats on it, but SQL Server doesn't need to allocate new resources as with a new connection. Between 2 and 4, they sound pretty much the same, just organized differently. I would suggest to make the code work and be maintainable / readable. Regarding passing data back, I was thinking in terms of a TVF passing back to the query.

Comment: @thomas : in order to give better advice, it would help to have more details on what you are trying to accomplish with this process and why you have the need for multiple connections in various places. It is quite likely that you could gain even more efficiency from reorganizing the overall process itself. Also, I reread the question and are you meaning that you will have multiple `SqlFunction` methods within the class? Or that there will be one exposed `SqlFunction` and the other methods will be `private`?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you can only have a single context connection open at a time.  So your #1 is how I've implemented it in the past.

I created my context connection in my entry function\sproc, and then passed it downstream to other methods.  The entry function was responsible for the lifecycle of the connection.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I am currently doing. Just thought it feels like extra passing around that might not be necessary. This CLR function will be called tens of millions times a day so trying to come up with ways to optimize as much as possible.